# Isomorphism of subrings of $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that the only subring of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is $\mathbb{Z}_m$ itself.

I'm wondering does this follow from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is cyclic and generated by $[1]_m$ and since $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is cyclic every subring must also. So for any subring $S$ of $\mathbb{Z}_m$ the ring $S$ must be cyclic so $$S=\langle[s]_m\rangle$$ but every cyclic group is either isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ or if it's finite with order $n$ then it's isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_n$.

The problems I see here are that $S$ may not be generated by element of order $m$ and so it would be isomorphic to some $\Bbb Z_n$ where $n < m$ and also is this fact true for rings even? That is is every cyclic ring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if the ring is of order $n$?

Comment: Depending on your definition of "ring", you may require (i) Rings to have a unity $1_R$; and (ii) subrings $S$ of $R$ to include the unity of $R$. Based on the statement, I'll bet both of those are true.

Comment: Yes indeed I have those conditions.

Comment: Well, then, if $S$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}_n$, then it must contain $[1]$, and since it must also be a subgroup....

Comment: Oh so it follows from there. It's therefore generated by element of order $m$ and isomorphic to $\mathbb{ Z}_m$?

Comment: No I guess not. Even if it's generated by $[1]$ also it has different order in $S$?

Comment: (i) Not isomorphic, **identical**. (ii) No, it cannot have "different order in $S$". In a subring, the operation has to be *exactly the same operation* as in the larger ring. Otherwise, it's not a "subring".

Comment: Okay. Are you saying then that since $S$ contains $[1]$ and is closed under addition it must be identical to $\Bbb Z_m$?

Comment: I'm was rather hoping you would realize it, yes.